# Qiskit - Z expectation value from counts?

Tags: qiskit, programming, measurement

For a given state $|\psi\rangle$, how would I work out $\langle\psi|Z|\psi\rangle$ ?

If I run a quantum circuit and get the counts dictionary on qiskit, I get observables in the Z basis.

For n=1 qubits, the basis states returned are $|0\rangle$ & $|1\rangle$ with the counts for each state. I would assign +1 to the counts for $|0\rangle$ and -1 to the counts for $|1\rangle$ and work out the Z expectation value.

For n=2 qubits, $|00\rangle$ & $|11\rangle$ have eigenvalues +1 and $|01\rangle$ &$|10\rangle$ have eigenvalues -1. The Z expectation value is thus [counts(00) + counts(11) - counts(01) - counts (10) ]/ shots where counts(00) is the counts returned for the $|00\rangle$ state.

This is extended to n = 3,4,5.. qubits.

My question is how do I calculate this automatically in qiskit?

Answer (score 7):

There's actually a really great way to evaluate this with [Qiskit Aqua's operator](https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/qiskit.aqua.operators.html) logic.

This module has the concept of statefunctions to represent $|\Psi\rangle$ and $\langle\Psi |$ and operators to represent operators such as $Z^{\otimes n}$.
Your operator would be created using the $Z$ primitive:

```
from qiskit.aqua.operators import Z

operator = Z ^ Z  # ^ represents a tensor product 
operator = Z ^ 2  # same thing, computes Z ^ Z
operator = Z.tensorpower(2)  # same thing as Z ^ 2
```

Now you need to create your state $|\Psi\rangle$, for which you have different options. Say you know the circuit to prepare your state, then you can do

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.aqua.operators import StateFn

psi_circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
# prepare your state ..
psi = StateFn(psi_circuit)  # wrap it into a statefunction
```

Or you can also use prepared common statefunctions such as `Zero` = $|0\rangle$, `One` = $|1\rangle$, `Plus` = $|+\rangle$ or `Minus` = $|-\rangle$,

```
from qiskit.aqua.operators import Zero, Plus


psi = Zero ^ Plus  # creates the state |0+>
```

To compute the expectation value you naturally need to evaluate $\langle \Psi | ZZ | \Psi\rangle$, which you can do as

```
expectation_value = (~psi @ operator @ psi).eval()
expectation_value = (psi.adjoint().compose(operator).compose(psi)).eval()  # same as above
```

To explain the syntax: `~` computes the adjoint, so `~psi` = $\langle\Psi|$. The `@` sign is composition and sticks together your states and operators.

#### Full example

As an example, let's compute the expectation value of $\langle \Psi| ZZ | \Psi\rangle$ with $|\Psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|01\rangle + |10\rangle)$.
Calculating by hand, this should yield $-1$.

```
import numpy as np
from qiskit.aqua.operators import Z, Zero, One

operator = Z ^ Z 
psi = 1 / np.sqrt(2) * ((One ^ Zero) + (Zero ^ One))
expectation_value = (~psi @ operator @ psi).eval()
print(expectation_value.real)  # -1.0
```

Comment: Can this method be implemented on a real QC? Or is this used only for simulating quantum circuits?

Comment: I'll answer my own question here. This method can be adapted to be run on a real QC as outlined here: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/12080/evaluating-expectation-values-of-operators-in-qiskit

Answer (score 4):

A function for finding the expectation value for the $Z Z  ... Z$ operator. If, for example, one wants to measure the expectation value of the $Z Z I$, instead of $Z Z Z$ than `z_index_list` should be provided (`z_index_list = [1, 2]`). Note that I have used the Qiskit's [ordering](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/3275cae1d8bd7e4628af63b4b697321c7118e15f/qiskit/quantum_info/operators/pauli.py#L75-L81) for Pauli labels.

```
def expectation_zzz(counts, shots, z_index_list=None):
    """
    :param shots: shots of the experiment
    :param counts: counts obtained from Qiskit's Result.get_counts()
    :param z_index_list: a list of indexes
    :return: the expectation value of ZZ...Z operator for given z_index_list
    """

    if z_index_list is None:
        z_counts = counts
    else:
        z_counts = cut_counts(counts, z_index_list)

    expectation = 0
    for key in z_counts:
        sign = -1
        if key.count('1') % 2 == 0:
            sign = 1
        expectation += sign * z_counts[key] / shots

    return expectation
```

The `cut_counts` function that will work if `z_index_list` is provided:

```
def cut_counts(counts, bit_indexes):
    """
    :param counts: counts obtained from Qiskit's Result.get_counts()
    :param bit_indexes: a list of indexes
    :return: new_counts for the  specified bit_indexes
    """
    bit_indexes.sort(reverse=True) 
    new_counts = {}
    for key in counts:
        new_key = ''
        for index in bit_indexes:
            new_key += key[-1 - index]
        if new_key in new_counts:
            new_counts[new_key] += counts[key]
        else:
            new_counts[new_key] = counts[key]

    return new_counts
```

For the arbitrary Pauli term $P$ before $ZZ...Z$ basis measurement one can apply a unitary operator $U$, such that:

$$ \langle \psi |P| \psi \rangle = \langle \psi | U^{\dagger} ZZ...Z U | \psi \rangle$$

like was described in this [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/11789/9459). Note that in $P$ we can have identities, so, for example, if we have $XIY$, we will need such $U$, that $U^{\dagger} ZIZ U = XIY$.

**Final notes**: here I assume that we have only one `ClassicalRegister`. If we have more then one `ClassicalRegister` I guess the code should be changed. The indexes are for the measured qubits (one can do fewer measurements than the numbers of the qubits in `QuantumRegister`), so, in general the `z_index_list` (and `bit_indexes`) doesn't coincide with the indexes of the qubits in the `QuantumRegister`.

Comment: I guess my actual question is how do I assign Z eigenvalues to the output states (ie the keys in the counts dictionary) 

For example 
Z eigenvalue of $\ket{0}$ is +1
Z eigenvalue of $\ket{1}$ is -1
Z eigenvalue of $\ket{00}$ is +1
Z eigenvalue of $\ket{11}$ is +1
Z eigenvalue of $\ket{10}$ is -1
Z eigenvalue of $\ket{01}$ is -1

Comment: @ZohimChandani, so your question is about the expectation value of $Z \otimes Z$ operator? Do you want to know how to write the code for it in Qiskit or do you want to understand what are the eigenvectors that have $+1$ ($-1$) eigenvalue? Can you, please, add more details about what are you looking for in your question by editing it?

Comment: Yes, what is the expectation value of Z for any number of qubits? I understand what eigenvectors have +1 and -1 eigenvalues but how do I assign these eigenvalues to the counts dictionary returned? I have edited the original question but let me know if it is still unclear.

Thanks

Comment: @Davit, could you please provide a modified version of your code in which only certain $Z$s (from the provided list, say `z_list=[0,3,4]`) would be measured? Thanks!

Comment: @mavzolej, I have changed my answer, now it includes the case described in your comment.

Comment: @Davit, amazing, thanks!! I guess, the list in your example should be `[0,1]`, using Qiskit notations?.. Also, is my understanding correct that in order to measure an arbitrary Pauli, the only extra step would be adding an additional layer of rotations to the quantum circuit before measuring, conditioned on which particular Pauli is to be calculated?

Comment: @mavzolej, happy to help :) I think the ordering is ok, it can be checked with the link that I have added in the answer. Yes, you are right, note that I have added a small explanation for the arbitrary Pauli term.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! TBH, I'm a little surprised that this whole procedure is not included into standard Qiskit library.

Comment: What exactly does the line `bit_indexes.sort(reverse=True)` do? (and why do we need it?)

Comment: @mavzolej, it sorts the indexes in decreasing order. It is added because if the function has received `[0, 5, 1, 2]` indexes, it will need to reorder them and it does reordering in decreasing order `[5, 2, 1, 0]` because that is the order that the
`for` loop that uses `bit_indexes` needs in the current implementation.

Comment: Could you please also explain why `cut_counts` produces a reduced number of counts? Shouldn't just some of the original counts be counted multiple times?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108455/discussion-between-davit-khachatryan-and-mavzolej).